# How find a value within an array, with a users input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
var x1 ='&spades',
    y1 ='&clubs'
    z1 ='&hearts';
var x2 = ' ', y2 = ' ', z2 = ' ';  
var x3 = ' ', y3 = ' ', z3 = ' ';    


var Array = [x1,y1,z1,
             x2,y2,z2,
             x3,y3,z3];
```

Then I get an input from the user asking them to select a location (ex. `x1`) store it as input 1, then ask them for another location (ex. `x2`) and store that as input 2, and I have to swap the locations of the value.

I initially tried something like `Array[input1] = Array[input2]`

But `Array[input1]` is undefined even though `input1 = x1` because `Array[x1]` is still undefined.

So how do I make `Array[x1] = Array[0]` so I can swap the values or is there an easier way?

Sorry if my question is poorly formed.

Comment: For starters, 'Array' is a keyword.  Probably not a good idea to use it as a variable name.  Next, the indices to your array are 0 through 9.  JS has no idea how to map 'x2' to 4.

Comment: use a variable to temporarily store the value of Array[firstValueToSwap] value and store the Array[secondValueToSwap] in Array[firstValueToSwap] and store the value in temp to Array[secondValueToSwap]. It's the easiest way to swap two values. BTW your question is not that clear. hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes the input is a string.

Comment: As per my understanding, you have an array with 9 elements in it. Example: [ '&spades', '&clubs',  '&hearts', ' ', ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ']. Now you want to swap the values at 2 indexes (input1 and input2) for example if the user entered 0 and 2. The new array will be [ '&hearts', '&clubs',  '&spades', ' ', ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , ' '].
I am writing this comment so that community can understand the question correctly.

Comment: @JimB. I know this isnt my real code my array is a lot bigger just a simple version, and I know that JS doesnt know how to map x2 to 4 but I was trying to see if there is any way otherwise i have to rewrite my program

Comment: Are you just wanting to retrieve data based on a string?  An object might be a better choice.

Comment: @Sanira Yes sorry I didn't know how to quite word what I was trying to do

Comment: @SuyashGulati Yes you have what I meant for the most part besides the user will be inputing the varable name like x1 not 0 the user wont know that x1 is in the 0 position. Other than that your are spot on

Comment: @JimB. I'm trying to receive a position of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the inputs are *strings* (`'x1'` and `'x2'`), you need a way to represent the variable names in your data structure. One way would be to have, rather than an array of strings, an array of objects, containing a `label` and a `value` property. Then, just find the indicies of both labels for both inputs, and reassign those indicies.

Also, better not to assign to a variable named `Array`, because that will *shadow* the global `Array` object - name it something else instead, like `arr`:

```js
const arr = [
  { label: 'x1', value: '&spades' },
  { label: 'y1', value: '&clubs' },
  { label: 'z1', value: '&hearts' }
  // ...
];
// Inputs:
const label1 = 'x1';
const label2 = 'y1';

// Calculate indicies:
const [index1, index2] = [label1, label2].map(
  findLabel => arr.findIndex(({ label }) => label === findLabel)
);
([arr[index1], arr[index2]] = [arr[index2], arr[index1]]);
console.log(arr);
```

The destructuring line at the end there allows for swapping variables in two positions at once, without having to resort to an intermediate variable:

```
([arr[index1], arr[index2]] = [arr[index2], arr[index1]]);
```

If you find that confusing, an alternative is to actually use an intermediate variable:

```
const orig1 = arr[index1];
arr[index1] = arr[index2];
arr[index2] = orig1;
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get back home, I see what you mean, I used a very very simple version of my code as an example of what I was trying to do I know not to name it array was just example but I will try to implement this method into my own code will let you know how it goes, thank you

Comment: Yes, thank you @CertainPerformance, by making my array of objects now allows me to make the connection between the array and users input so now I can switch them, at the bottom I get a bit fuzzy on how the whole switching works, I just used some if statements with an intermediate var because I didnt understand what the bottom half was doing. Though I will try to play around to try and understand it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your code might look like if you use an object:

```js
    let arr = {};
    arr['x1'] = '&spades';
    arr['y1'] = '&clubs';
    arr['z1'] = '&hearts';
    arr['x2'] = ' ';
    arr['y2'] = ' ';
    arr['z2'] = ' ';
    arr['x3'] = ' ';
    arr['y3'] = ' ';
    arr['z3'] = ' ';
    
    console.log(arr['z1']);
    arr['z1'] = 'foo';
    console.log(arr['z1']);
```

Comment: I see what you mean now CertainPerformace was saying something about the same will try as soon as I can, thank you

Comment: Yes, @JimB. you were right the answer was that I had to make an array of objects. Thank you for your help.